# Mpdf check to see if content goes on multipule pages

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

I am creating an invoice using mpdf. I am rendering a table in html and displaying it with mpdf. If the table is too long for one page I would like to add a 'continue on next page' message.
Is there any way of knowing if the content will go onto multipul pages or dynamically break content onto multiple pages?
Any help would be much appreciated!